# Unable to import kafkaProducer for Syntax error in Library

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, kafka-python

I have installed the latest version **Kafka** using `pip install`

```
Installing collected packages: kafka
Successfully installed kafka-1.3.5
```

When I try to `import KafkaProducer` it gives me the **error** :

```
  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer

  File "//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
                                                  ^
```

I have tried two other versions too, but all seem to be giving the similar error.
    **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: Well, this is it: `async` is now a keyword, so it can't be used as an attribute name. Check if you've installed the latest version of the library and that it supports your Python version (looks like it doesn't)

Comment: @ForceBru, I get the point, but I am using Version 1.3.5 as mentioned and Python version 3.4+, ideally version compatibility should not be the issue.

Comment: [here](https://pypi.org/project/kafka/) it says "Python 3.4, 3.5, 3.6", so your version (3.7) is not supported. Indeed, in Python 3.6 `async` and `await` are not keywords, unlike in 3.7

Comment: There are other Kafka libraries for python, by the way

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the python version 3.7 which is not supported.

Go through this: https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/

```sh
pip3 install kafka-python
```